# django how do i send a post_save signal when updating a user?

Tags: django, django-signals

having read the docs,

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

i have created this in my signals.py file:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from models import User

from models import Story

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_initial_story(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    print "helloooo!"
    if created:
        Story(user = instance, title = 'Random Stories', description="Random stories", is_closed = False, is_random = True).save()
```

which, from what i read, was all i thought i needed to do to send a message. Well, that and create a new user (i use the django-registration framework) However, nothing is being sent (well, the receiver method i have does nothing). I also removed the "sender=User" parameter to the @receiver annotation - leaving

```
@receiver(post_save)
```

but that did not help matters. Nothing is output to the console, no new data is saved... do i need to *send* the signal from the User when the User is saved?? If so, how would i do that? I am using django-registration, so i have a UserProfile defined... what i mean is, where (in what file/method) would i tell the User to send the signal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should import your `signals.py` somewhere to run it. For example in `models.py`.

Comment: hm, am a bit new to python - so aside from the import signals line, do i need to *call* it in the models.py? Or can i just, well, import it and leave it at that?

Comment: @bharal Just import. You need to just run it somehow. And use `django.db.models.get_model` in `signals.py` to prevent circular imports.

Answer (score 6):

First, they're called "decorators". Annotations are something else in Django, so best not to confuse terminology there.

The `post_save` signal is called, as its name implies, after every save. Specifying `sender` limits the receiver to just `post_save` signals sent for saves of that particular model. If you leave it out, your receiver will be called when *any* model is saved, which is surely not what you want.

Your problem here is that your receiver, for all intents and purposes doesn't *exist*. Django does not import automatically import `signals.py` for you, so it's never seen. The only way to get it seen is to import it somewhere that Django does look at, such as models.py (as @DrTyrsa) suggests.

However, if you do that, you're going to end up with a circular import error, since you're importing models.py into signals.py already. So, you can either just put your signal code directly into models.py, or find somewhere else to import it; `__init__.py` might work, but I normally just always put my signals in models.py and call it a day.

Comment: Or use `django.db.models.get_model`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.